# Excel VBA seperate data from cells into seperate columns

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me with a vba code to separate cells text from 1 Cel into different cells in another workbook.
For instance

- Data from Column A Sheet 1

```
    Column A row 1; XX-SS100000-A00000_000
    Column A row 2; XXX-SS155555-A55555-55_555
    ...
```

- into Column A,B,C,D Sheet 2

```
Column A row 1 XXX
Column B row 1 SS100000
Column C row 1 A00000
Column D row 1 000

Column A row 2 XX
Column B row 2 SS15555
Column C row 2 A55555-55
Column D row 2 555
```

[Data in Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RUcn.png)

[Converted dat in Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqDad.png)

Comment: It's necessary to explain your logic by editing your post. Is there a fixed number of outputs, does only the third item include a possible sub-hypen etc? Otherwise your question risks to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim cSrc As Range, cDest As Range, v, arr
    Set cSrc = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    Set cDest = Sheet2.Range("A1")
    
    Do While Len(cSrc.Value) > 0
        
        arr = Split(cSrc.Value, "_") 'split on underscore
        
        cDest.Resize(1, 4).NumberFormat = "@"             'set numberformat to Text
        cDest.Resize(1, 3).Value = Split(arr(0), "-", 3)  'limit to 3 outputs
        cDest.Offset(0, 3).Value = arr(1)                 'part after the "_"
        
        Set cSrc = cSrc.Offset(1, 0)
        Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1, 0)
    
    Loop
    
End Sub
```